Is there a common first thing we all know as a fetus?
Is there a common first truth known to any fetus, and if there is what is it?  I was thinking of Descartes' methodological doubt, wherein he arrived at the indubitable truth "I think therefore I am.". I wonder, is there some grand unifying epistemological truth that can serve as the foundation of epistemology?  Is there a first thing known to all animals, regardless of their species?  This question leads to other interesting questions like "what things can be known before birth," innate knowledge if you will.  And if we divide all knowledge into two mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive classes, a priori knowledge and a posteriori knowledge, to which class does this first epistemic truth belong?

a priori knowledge: knowledge gained through reason
a posteriori knowledge: knowledge not gained through reason.

Knowledge gained through the senses or knowledge gained through experience would be considered a posteriori knowledge.

Interesting question! There is good evidence that fetus can hear, remember etc. See. If you dont mind mythology heres a more extreme story

I probably (re)discovered The Fundamental Principles of Epistemology, which is that 1. All Truths Are Knowable and that 2. Reality Is Comprehensible. Read up on Fitch's Paradox Of Knowability

"Gosh! There's not much room in here!"

you'll probably run into the hard problem of conciousness, which is to say that in order to answer this question you need to know what it is to be a fetus or an animal. For example, does a fish run away from a bigger fish because it has some knowledge of itself as a fich and a will of self preservation, like me and (presumably) you, or just because it is hardwired to mechanically react to certain stimuli, like a philosophical zombie? If it's the latter a fish can't know anything because it has no conciousness. But to know that you would have to be fish.

And if the fish couldn't know anything, and you came to know what it was to be a fish, then

One area you could look in to is how people develop who have been deaf and blind since birth? Do they ever become able to use language? If so, what do they say about their experience?
